# How to ensure if an SSH tunnling failed (if I haven't really tunneled)

Tags: ssh, ports, tunneling, websocket

I tunneled data transition as `22-22` and `2222-80`, between my PC and VPS:

```
ssh user@1.1.1.1 -L 22:localhost:22 -L 2222:localhost:80 -i ~/.ssh/key
```

To make sure both tunnels were created, I executed `lsof -i -n -P | grep ^ssh` after logging in to the server.

Here is the stdout. You can see that only port `22` is present, without `2222`:

```
sshd     1785     root    3u  IPv4  17568      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd     1785     root    4u  IPv6  17570      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd    31511     root    3u  IPv4 447661      0t0  TCP SERVER_IP:ssh->ISP-acronym-LOCAL_IP.ISP-subdomain.ISP-domain:52086 (ESTABLISHED)
```

### My question:

My question can actually be comprised of the following 2 questions:

1. What might have went wrong so that only a `22` tunnel appears, but no `2222` tunnel? Please advise me what's worth checking in my system and I will update this question.
2. What is this IPV6 there in the second column? Neither my PC, nor my VPS, has a IPV6 IP.

### Notes:

1. The system I tunnel from is WSL Ubuntu. Very basic; A fresh install with no utilities installed besides fail2ban. I just login with the already existing OpenSSH and that's basically it.

Comment: You are apparently looking at `sshd` _on the server_. (Maybe you typed this _in_ the remote shell run and connected by `ssh`?) The LISTENs for `-L` tunnels _should be on the client_ where you are running `ssh`.(Also `-D`, while `-R` LISTENs on the server and tunnels to the client.) I don't know if WSL has `lsof`; if not try `netstat` or `ss`. Re IPv6: if real Linux the server has a dual _stack_ whether or not it has an IPv6 _address_.

Comment: I typed this in the remote shell (VPS), indeed. Also, indeed it seems current release of WSL doesn't have `lsof`... `netstat` or `ss` doesn't seem to return any values at all when I run them in a second, local WSL session (after I already logged in). Please honor me with any other advise you might have.

Comment: WSL does have lsof, netstat and ss. Make sure you are up-to-date with Windows updates AND that you have done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Of course, that doesn't mean they return quite the same information than on a real Ubuntu Linux system. Certainly not all system-level information is available to the Ubuntu subsystem due to the different way that the Windows Core works. I'm not even sure if running another window creates a separate environment, you might need to use screen.

Comment: Is there no way to check if both tunnels were established from the VPS's end?

Comment: If you're host (*my PC*) hold a SSH server, you won't be able to listen on port 22.

Comment: Instead of binding port 22, have a look in manpage, at `-M` and `-S` switchs to `ssh`!

Comment: It's tangental, but if SSH tunnels collapsing often is a concern, you might want to look into autossh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `netstat -tulpn` I did saw to conenctions, one is to port 22, and one is to port 80.

**So it seems the tunneling didn't fail.**